# Detecting if key was pressed by pyautogui

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui

How can we check if key was pressed down by python? keyboard.is_pressed not working, probably bcause it wasn't pressed from keyboard.

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard

pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
if keyboard.is_pressed('shift') == True:
    print('Shift is down')
else:
    print('Shift is up')
    
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it is only executing ONE time, which is when the code is executed.
You can use a `while` loop, which will execute every frame. But I recommend creating a "wait until" function, which means, it will wait UNTIL the condition is true.
Example of what you can do:

```py
    import time
    
    def wait_until(condition):
        while not condition:
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust the delay as needed
        # Condition is now true, continue with the rest of your code
    
    # Example usage
    x = 0
    wait_until(lambda: x > 5)
    print("x is now greater than 5")
```

So, in your case, we don't need that, but I've told this because it is very important! By the way, the code would be this:

```py
    import time
    import pyautogui
    import keyboard
    
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('shift') == True:
            print('Shift is down')
        else:
            print('Shift is up')
```

If it doesn't work, you can comment on this post, and I will reply you with corrections!